# Create Mongo Collection With Meteor When a User Registers

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on a Meteor application to allow staff of a music venue to say if they are available to work each shift in a month or not. All that I have left to do is to make it so that a Mongo collection is created for a user when they register so that the original data is never changed and only the documents relating to that user is displayed. I have thought about only having one collection with each document in it having an owner ID but this would result in either the original data and the users duplicate data being displayed at the same time or no data being displayed as no documents will have their user ID when they first register.

Is there a way to create a collection on both the client and server when a user registers? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean  the issue is when you say "no data being displayed as no documents will have their user ID when they first register"? Wouldn't that be normal, if the user has just signed up to the service and hasn't been able to provide any information yet?

Comment: When they first register I need there to be a table with all of the available shifts. I can get this from the 'shows' collection but I do not want the original data to be edited as it needs to be kept for any other user that registers after. Essentially, I need to copy the original data when a user registers and that needs to be the default data for that user.

Comment: Don't you want a given user's dataset to evolve when other users take shifts though? You'd have to maintain all of those copies reactively... I think you should create one collection with an ownership field like you said, and give `update` and `insert` allowing permissions according to `doc && doc.ownerId === userId`

Comment: How do I copy the original data into the same collection and then add in the owner ID? Would copying the data, in whichever way I can, generate a new object ID or would it duplicate it?

Comment: No need to copy the original data if you are using one single collection: the original data is already there. If I understood correctly, you just need to ensure that the user cannot modify, create or delete data that is not linked to him through `ownerId`. And for that, you would use the `yourCollection.allow()` method

Comment: Each document has a date, event, time and available field. The user can edit the documents to say if they are available or not and then after the shift they can add in the time that they started and finished. How do I link the original data, that is in the collection before any users register, to each user as they register without changing the original data? Just now I have 150 documents that need to be linked to each user. Only the documents that relate to them will be published so I would need to create 150 new documents that are near_duplicates of the original, but with the userID also. No?